# Batch Update Symbolic Links Recursively

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I have a web app that has a bunch of symbolic links in subdirectories throughout it.  I need to move the app to another directory structure, and I need to update all the symlinks to point to the new path.  For example:

Old Dir: `/home/user/public_html/dev`
New Dir: `/home/user/public_html/qa`
Old Symlink: `/home/user/public_html/qa/multisites/slave01/images -> /home/user/public_html/dev/images`
New Symlink: `/home/user/public_html/qa/multisites/slave01/images -> /home/user/public_html/qa/images`

The problem is that there's a lot of these scattered throughout various directories.  How can I recursively search from the root and recreate all symlinks pointing to `/dev/` with `/qa/`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This bash command should do it for you:

```
find /home/user/public_html/qa/ -type l -lname '/home/user/public_html/dev/*' -printf 'ln -nsf "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/dev/qa/)" "$(echo "%p" | sed s/dev/qa/)"\n' > script.sh
```

It uses `find` to identify all files in the `qa` directory that are symbolic links with a target that's in the `dev` directory, and for each one, it prints out a bash command that will replace the link with a link to the equivalent path in `qa/`. After you run this, just execute the generated script with

```
bash script.sh
```

You might want to examine it manually first to make sure it worked.

Here's a more verbose version of the above `find` command for easier reading (though I wouldn't necessarily write it this way in practice):

```
SRC_DIR="/home/user/public_html/qa"
OLD_TARGET="/home/user/public_html/dev"
SUB="s/dev/qa/"

find $SRC_DIR -type l \
  -lname "$OLD_TARGET/*" -printf \
  'ln -nsf "$(readlink "%p"|sed $SUB)" "$(echo "%p"|sed $SUB)"\n'\
 > script.sh
```

Comment: This creates an empty script.sh.  And running the find command as so:  `find /home/user/public_html/qa/ -type l -lname '/home/user/public_html/dev/*'`  doesn't output anything.

Comment: You did remember to change the paths to the actual ones on your filesystem, right? What happens if you run just `find /home/usr/public_html/qa/ -type l`? If that doesn't find the links, something very weird is going on with your system.

Comment: Yes, "`find /home/user/public_html/qa/ -type l`" outputs the links.  But adding the -lname parameter it doesn't output anything.

Comment: Actually, on further testing it looks like this is working.  Not sure what I was doing wrong yesterday, but seems ok now.  Thanks.

Comment: Huh, weird. Well, if you ever figure out what was going wrong, put a comment here. I'm curious.

Comment: This fails for me, perhaps because I have spaces in paths?

Comment: @Sparhawk probably. To get around that you should use double quotes around both instances of `%p`.

Comment: @DavidZ I've since renamed them manually (like a n00b), but I suspect that one would also need literal quotes that are written to `script.sh`.

Comment: @Sparhawk yes, the double quotes I suggested adding are precisely the same ones that would be literally written to `script.sh`.

Comment: @DavidZ Sorry, my language was messed up. I mean that the entirety of the `readlink…|sed…` pipe should be contained in literal quotes, otherwise the command substitution will be split after the `readlink` pipe is executed. i.e. something like `'ln -nsf "$(re...`

Comment: @Sparhawk oh, yeah, I see what you mean now. I missed that. I guess I may as well edit it in.

Comment: Worked great for me, thanks! In my case, there were only files, and only the target destination changed, which allowed for some simplification: $ find . -type l -lname '\*regex\*' -printf 'ln -sf "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/old/new/)" "%p"\n' > script.sh

Comment: As many people want to change /path/to/directory to /somewhere/else/completely (rather than just the last directory name), it would be much more robust for this solution to not use s/old/new notation as the slashes get in the way. I'm struggling to get this answer working for my use case.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone else finds this when searching for a solution:
Create a file named "linkmod.sh" containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATTERN1=`echo "$2"`
PATTERN2=`echo "$3"`
LINKNAME=`echo "$1"`
OLDTARGET=`readlink "$1"`
NEWTARGET=`echo "$OLDTARGET" \
| sed -e 's/'"$PATTERN1"'/'"$PATTERN2"'/'`
echo ln -nsf "$NEWTARGET" "$LINKNAME"
```

and run

```
find . -type l -print0 | xargs -0IX echo linkmod.sh X "pattern1" "pattern2"
```

You can ofc use the -lname option in find if needed.

NOTE: you have to use 2x \ in the patterns before any characters that require \ in sed, since echo removes one. For example

```
find . -type l -print0 | xargs -0IX echo linkmod.sh X "folder\\ name\\/file" "folder2\\ name\\/file"
```

Remove the `echo` from the last line if the ln commands are correct.

Comment: Might be good to clarify that both the `echo` in the final line of the *script* and the `echo` in the `find .. | xargs .. linkmod.sh ...` command itself *both* need to be removed.

Answer (score 4):

I created a bash script `link_rename.sh` for the recursively renaming symbolic links in a given directory

```
#! /bin/bash

DIR=$1
OLD_PATTERN=$2
NEW_PATTERN=$3

while read -r line
do
    echo $line
    CUR_LINK_PATH="$(readlink "$line")"
    NEW_LINK_PATH="$CUR_LINK_PATH"  
    NEW_LINK_PATH="${NEW_LINK_PATH/"$OLD_PATTERN"/"$NEW_PATTERN"}"
    rm "$line"
    ln -s "$NEW_LINK_PATH" "$line"
done <<< $(find "$DIR" -type l)
```

It can be executed as `link_rename.sh /home/human/dir link1 link2`

The script has 3 arguments:

1. The directory in which you want to perform the batch rename of symlinks
2. The old pattern. Here `link1` is the old pattern which will be replaced
3. The new pattern. Here `link2` is the new pattern with which `link1` will be replaced

The script recursively reads all symlinks in the directory using `find "$DIR" -type l`
and processes it line by line.

`$line` is the symlink which needs to be renamed

`CUR_LINK_PATH` is the old path

`NEW_LINK_PATH` is obtained by performing string replacement in the old link path.

The old symlink is removed and new symlink is created using `ln -s "$NEW_LINK_PATH" "$line"`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a command-line PHP script which seems to do the trick.

```
<?php
//Run via command-line
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.');
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $file) {
    //$link = readlink($file);
    if(is_link($file)) {
        $old_link = readlink($file);
        $new_link = str_ireplace("/joomla/", "/qa/", $old_link);
        if($new_link != $old_link) {
            exec('rm "'.$file.'"');
            exec('ln -fs "'.$new_link.'" "'.$file.'"');
            $new_link = readlink($file);
            if($new_link == $old_link) {
                echo $file."\t".$old_link."\t".$new_link."\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while trying to change symbolic links for PHP fpm from version 8.0 to 8.1. This command is what worked for me without a lot of hassle.

```
find /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d -type l -lname '/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/*' -exec bash -c "readlink {} |sed s/8.0/8.1/| xargs -I % ln -nsf % {}" \;
```

Comment: Hi, Code only answers are not complete.  For instance, its impossible to figure out if the answer is correct without looking at references.  So, please edit you answer and explain what each bit does,